# Are derivatives of geometric progressions all irreducible?

Tags: reference-request, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, open-problem

Consider the polynomials $P_n(x)=1+2x+3x^2+\dots+nx^{n-1}$. Problem A5 in 2014 Putnam competition was to prove that these polynomials are pairwise relatively prime. In the solution sheet there is the following remark:

> It seems likely that the individual polynomials $P_k(x)$ are all irreducible, but this appears difficult to prove.

My question is exactly about this: is it known if all these polynomials are irreducible? Or is it an open problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3218248/family-of-irreducible-polynomials/3231579#3231579

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the article [Classes of polynomials having only one non-cyclotomic irreducible factor](http://www.pitt.edu/%7Eborisov/Documents/papers/noncycl.pdf)  the authors (A. Borisov, M. Filaseta, T. Y. Lam, and O. Trifonov) had proved for any $\epsilon > 0$ for all but $O(t^{(1/3)+\epsilon})$ positive integers $n\leq  t$, the derivative of the polynomial $f(x)= 1+ x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n$ is irreducible, and in general for all $n\in \mathbb N$ they **conjectured** $f'(x)$ is irreducible.