# Prove that the polynomial $P(x) = x^{p−1} + 2x^{p−2} + 3x^{p−3} +···+ (p − 1)x + p$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[x].$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p$ be a prime number. Prove that the polynomial
$P(x) = x^{p−1} + 2x^{p−2} + 3x^{p−3} +···+ (p − 1)x + p$
is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[x].$

The Eisenstein-Schönemann theorem cannot be used to conclude anything at this stage.
Is there some other method to prove this?
This was a question that required only elementary mathematics i.e. fields etc. are not required.

Comment: For primes $p = 1 \mod 4$ we can use $\mod 2$ test. The other case remains to be solved.

Comment: Or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3218248/11619).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Easy! Thanks. Could you elaborate about what the first comment to this question is trying to refer to?

Comment: @Infinity_hunter Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a clue what the first comment means. When reduced modulo $2$ the polynomial becomes a perfect square in $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$ modulo every prime, so cannot be that.