# Irreducibility of $(n+1)+nx+(n-1)x^2+\ldots+x^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I'm trying to prove the irreducibility over the rationals of the polynomial defined by

$$f(x)=(n+1)+nx+(n-1)x^2\ldots+x^n$$

for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Computationally, I've verified it is always irreducible up to $n=4096$. It seems like it should be a polynomial that has been studied before, so I'm wondering if anyone recognizes it or if there's a simple trick I'm just missing. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Family of irreducible polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3218248/family-of-irreducible-polynomials). There does not seem to be a definitive answer, but partial ones and some useful links.